# How to generate a numerical table?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following issue for generating a table in Mathematica.
How to generate a table with the limits 10^-18 to 10^-6 with steps of (1,2,3, ....10)*10^-1? e.g. It should look of the following form:

```
{1*10^-18, 2*10^-18, 3*10^-18,........1*10^-17, 2*10^-17, 3*10^-17,.......1*10^-16......1*10^-7, 2*10^-7, 2*10^-7,......9*10^-7, 1*10^-6}.
```

Could someone please have a look at this?

Comment: I mean, you can feed that specific list of values in `Table[]`: `Table[f[x], {x, {1*10^-18, 2*10^-18, ...}}]`...

Comment: @ J. M.: I don't want to feed values in explicit form because it would be too long. 10* 12=120! I want to do this Table[x, {x, 10^-18,10^-6, step?}]

Comment: You might want to use `Range` instead of `Table`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: Show it please.

Comment: So, you basically want to map over the output of `Append[Flatten[KroneckerProduct[PowerRange[1*^-18, 1*^-7], Range[9]]], 1*^-6]`?

Comment: Try this as an example: `Table[Range[1.*10^(-18 + n), 1*10^(-17 + n), 1*10^(-18 + n)], {n, 0, 4}] // Flatten`.

Comment: Try also this: `Flatten[Range[1.*10^(-18 + #), 1*10^(-17 + #), 1*10^(-18 + #)] & /@Range[1, 3]]`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: In your first solution there are repetitions in the generated table.

Comment: Have you seen `DeleteDuplicates`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are going to be multiple ways to do this, but here's one:

```
Table[
  mantissa exponent,
  {exponent, PowerRange[10^-18, 10^-7]},
  {mantissa, 9}
] ~ Join ~ {10^-6} ~ Flatten ~ 1 // N

(* Out:
{1.*^-18, 2.*^-18, 3.*^-18, 4.*^-18, ... 8.*^-7, 9.*^-7, 1.*^-6}
*)
```

---

Answering the comment about finer granularity:

````
Table[
   mantissa exponent,
   {exponent, PowerRange[10^-18, 10^-8]},
   {mantissa, 10, 99}
] ~ Join ~ {10^-6} ~ Flatten ~ 1 // N

(* Out:
{1. *10^-17, 1.1*10^-17, 1.2*10^-17, 1.3*10^-17, 1.4*10^-17, 
 1.5*10^-17, 1.6*10^-17, 1.7*10^-17, 1.8*10^-17, 1.9*10^-17, 
 2. *10^-17, 2.1*10^-17, 2.2*10^-17, 2.3*10^-17, 2.4*10^-17, 
 ... 
 9.2*10^-7,  9.3*10^-7,  9.4*10^-7,  9.5*10^-7,  9.6*10^-7, 
 9.7*10^-7, 9.8*10^-7, 9.9*10^-7, 1.*10^-6}
*)
```
````

Comment: I wonder why the normal way Table[x, {x, xmin,xmax, steps}] does not work?

Comment: Also, how to further divide the steps in between the two consecutive powers. e.g  (* Out: {1.*^-18, 1.1*^-18, 1.2*^-18 , 1.3*^-18, 1.4*^-18, 1.5*^-18, 1.6*^-18, 1.7*^-18,  1.8*^-18,  1.9*^-18,  2.*^-18, ..........3.*^-18, ........4.*^-18, ... 8.*^-7, 9.*^-7, 1.*^-6}
*)

Comment: @Sci, because that syntax of `Table[]` is not meant for irregular steps like yours. That's what the other syntax I showed is for: `Table[f[x], {x, N @ Append[Flatten[KroneckerProduct[PowerRange[1*^-18, 1*^-7], Range[9]]], 1*^-6]}]`.

Comment: @SciJewel See edit for finer granularity

Comment: @MarcoB: Great! however, some further refinement is needed in your granularity post. When I apply your great method on the following range: : {3.1*10^-13, 10^-6}, it gives me the output: {3.1*10^-13, 6.2*10^-13, 9.3*10^-13........}, while I expect it to be: {3.1*10^-13, 3.2*10^-13, 3.3*10^-13.........} Notice it skips 3.2 and instead gives 6.2.

Comment: @SciJewel How exactly did you change the code in your last case?

Comment: @MarcoB: I exactly want:  {3.1*10^-13, 3.2*10^-13, 3.3*10^-13...........1.*10^-6}

Comment: @SciJewel First generate the whole set by modifying the code above, then use `Select[wholeListFromAbove, # >= 3.1*^-13]`.

Answer (score 3):

Producing accurate numbers using "Outer":

```
Outer[#2 10^#1 &, Range[-16, -6], Range[9]] // Flatten
```

[image]

Or producing machine numbers:

```
Outer[#2 10^#1 &, Range[-16, -6], Range[9]] // Flatten  // N
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: How to further divide e.g. 1.1*10^-16, 1.2*10^-16, 1.4*10^-16.......1.9*10^-16........10^-17..........10^-6

Comment: Replace `Range[9]` with `Range[1,9.9,0.1]`.